# Interactively, don't allow the first character in a text input to be a space, or group of spaces

Tags: javascript

Firstly, This is NOT a repeat question. Most of the similar questions, I've come across, don't preform the desired action *interactively (e.g. "onkeydown", "onkeyup", etc.)*. I need a *pure JavaScript (i.e. **NO jQuery**)* function to disallow the first character of a text-based input to be a space or group of spaces given just the elements ID. Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/* Don't allow the first character of a "text-based" input element
 * (e.g. text-box, text-area, editable-div's) to be a space, given
 * the elements ID ([ eID ]). [BEGIN]
 */

function noPrecedingSpace ( eID )
{

    var elmt = document.getElementById(eID);

    elmt.addEventListener("keydown", function(event)
    { 
        var strg = elmt.value;
        var lastChar = strg.charAt(strg.length - 1);

        if ((lastChar == " ")||(lastChar == "&nbsp;")||(strg == ""))
        {
            return event.which !== 32;
        };
    }); 

};

/* Don't allow the first character of a "text-based" input element
 * (e.g. text-box, text-area, editable-div's) to be a space, given the
 * elements ID ([ eID ]). [END]
 */

</script>
```

Any ideas as to why this is not working?

What am I doing wrong?

Please Note: "Paste" is already accounted for, and disallowed on the field by another javascript, that, by the way, is working perfectly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesAndersonJr/oxyetwkz/)

Comment: How should this appear to the user, what affect are you after? You seem to want to stop the actual event but what about just stripping off the white space at the start of the element value? Do you need to do this on every key stroke or can you wait until the element looses focus?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle to test it out?

Comment: Yes, It's necessary to check this on every keystroke because the field is a `"visitors_name"` field, and nobody's name starts with a space. additional I have another script to capitalize the first letter of every word in the field, so the name will be correctly capitalized, and yet another script to disallow numbers (obviously, unless they're an alien with numbers in their name). The space breaks/confuses the capitalization script (the 1st one I mentioned).

Comment: I guess you have a specific need for this style of form validation but maybe read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Depending on what browsers you need to support there is also the [HTML5 pattern attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-introduction-and-new-attributes/#pattern) but you'll need a modern browser [Can I Use: Pattern attribute for input fields](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning true/false is the "old" way of managing event propagation. Better now is to use `preventDefault()`

```
var elmt = document.getElementById('noSpaces');

elmt.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (elmt.value.length === 0 && event.which === 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This just checks... if the current input length is zero then a space is not allowed.

Also see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/6nmdpypb/).

You can add/modify to check for non-breaking spaces also, if that's really a problem -- match with a regex like Dave's answer, but only if `elmt.value.length` is `> 0`

This, however, would let you type non-spaces, then *back-up* to the start of the field and insert spaces.
A [revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/6nmdpypb/1/) trims leading whitespace as you're typing, but this also won't entirely solve the problem.

```
var elmt = document.getElementById('noSpaces');

elmt.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 32) {
        elmt.value = elmt.value.replace(/^\s+/, '');
        if (elmt.value.length === 0) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

You can keep refining it, even taking the current caret position and the currently selected text into account, but ultimately you ***must*** `.trim()` the string you receive on the *server*, since I (for one) can send you anything I want to send despite all of your javascript efforts to make me enter a "legal" string.

Comment: Looks good, but with this name field, I don't want more than one space between the words either (which is why I was trying to do it the way I was). Can your code be modified to prevent this? Kind of like a dual-purpose script?

Comment: @James well sure it can be modified to your heart's content. Keep in mind that you can both modify the element's current value and also decide whether or not you want to `preventDefault()` based on the key pressed and any aspect of the element value, before and/or after you modify it. You can also, as I hint at, check where the insertion point currently is and look at the characters surrounding that. But again, ultimately,  I must _emphasize_, you need to check and possibly modify the value that you receive on the server. _**Do Not Trust**_ _the data coming from the browser!_

Comment: Good Advice! BTW, with your help, I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesAndersonJr/oxyetwkz/2/) working script. Thanks!

Comment: I used following your ideea i used `onKeyDown={ e => e.target.value.length == 0 && e.key === " " && e.preventDefault() && e.stopPropagation() }` - > this is react but the ideea is I replaced deprecated `.which` with `.key`

Answer (score 3):

You can test the value of the input with a regular expression to see if it starts with a space and if so remove the spaces from the start of the value;

```
var input = document.getElementById('noSpaces');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
   if(/^\s/.test(input.value)) {
     input.value = input.value.replace(/^\s+/,'');   
   }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7mvo98a/5/)

Comment: One minor change — I held down the spacebar, inserting a bunch of spaces, and only the _last_ space was removed. Change your replace regex to `input.value.replace(/^\s+/,'');` To be consistent, you might also want the test regex to be `if (/^\s+/ ...)`

Comment: Thanks but I really need on "onkeydown", because  1.) my "onkeyup" is already assigned to another function (remember the capitalization script I mentioned?), and 2.) "onkeyup" is too slow I want the space to be caught before it ever reaches the field (e.g. something like `return false;`).

Comment: here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesAndersonJr/oxyetwkz/), not working though! :-(

Comment: @DaveAnderson Any ideas as to why [_my_](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesAndersonJr/oxyetwkz/) code is not working? I must be missing something...

Comment: @JamesAndersonJr. more than one handler can be assigned to an event if you are using `addEventListener( ... )` so you can use keyup for both purposes, but see my answer for a keydown handler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @StephenP, I have come up with this final answer, which is just perfect for my needs ("visitors_name" field):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/* Don't allow the first character of a "text-based" input element (e.g. text-box, text-area, editable-div's, etc.) to be a space, given the elements ID ([ eID ]). Also, don't allow more than one space between adjacent words. [BEGIN] */
/* Usage Example: noPrecedingOrDoubleSpace ("visitors_name"); */

function noPrecedingOrDoubleSpace ( eID )
{

var elmt = document.getElementById(eID);

elmt.addEventListener("keydown", function(event)
{ 
var strg = elmt.value;
var lastChar = strg.charAt(strg.length - 1);

if ((lastChar == " ")||(lastChar == "&nbsp;")||(strg == ""))
{
if (event.which === 32)
{
event.preventDefault();  
};
};
});

};

/* Don't allow the first character of a "text-based" input element (e.g. text-box, text-area, editable-div's, etc.) to be a space, given the elements ID ([ eID ]). Also, don't allow more than one space between adjacent words. [END] */

</script>
```

Keep in mind that if you just need no space, only at the *beginning* of the input, @StephenP's answer is probably more practical, and is the *real* answer to this question, given the title.

Also remember, that just as @StephenP mentioned, real validation is best done in the server-side script (e.g. php). This JavaScript is just to *encourage* correct input formatting. Nothing more, nothing less.

Big kudos to @StephenP

Thanks!

[Final JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesAndersonJr/oxyetwkz/4/).

Comment: Thanks for the thanks!  Note with this that after typing according to the rules, you _can_ go back (left-arrow) and add spaces at the start and add more than one space in between words.  That is often acceptable when input processing is meant to prevent accidents, because in the case I outline someone is clearly doing that intentionally.